# GLSL blending input texture with target FBO color attachment

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have a system which allows me to set different blending modes (Those found in Photoshop) for each renderable object.Currently what I do is :

1. Render the renderable Object into FBO B normally.
2. Attach blending mode shader program,FBO C , and blend color attachment from FBO B with color attachment from FBO A (FBO A contains previous draws final result).
3. Blit the result from FBO C into FBO A and proceed with the rest of pipeline .

While this works fine , I would like to spare some frame rate which is currently wasted for this ping pong.I know that by default it is not possible to read pixels at the same time when writing to them so it is not possible to set a texture to read from and write to? Ideally ,What I would like to do is in the stage 1 render geometry right into FBO A processing the blend between FBO A color attachment texture and input material texture.

To make it clear here is the example.

Let's assume all the previously rendered geometry is accumulated in FBO A.And each new rendered object that needs to get blended is rendered into FBO B (just like I wrote above).Then in the blend pass (drawn into FBO C) the following shader is used (here it is darken blending )  :

```
uniform sampler2D bottomSampler;
uniform sampler2D topSampler;
uniform float Opacity;


// utility function that assumes NON-pre-multiplied RGB...
vec4 final_mix(
    vec4 NewColor,
    vec4 BaseColor,
    vec4 BlendColor
 ) {
 float A2 = BlendColor.a * Opacity;
 vec3 mixRGB = A2 * NewColor.rgb;
 mixRGB += ((1.0-A2) * BaseColor.rgb);
 return vec4(mixRGB,BaseColor.a+BlendColor.a);
}

void main(void) // fragment
{
vec4 botColor = texture2D(bottomSampler,gl_TexCoord[0].st);
vec4 topColor = texture2D(topSampler,gl_TexCoord[0].st);
vec4 comp = final_mix(min(botColor,topColor),botColor,topColor);
    gl_FragColor = comp;
}
```

Here  :

**uniform sampler2D bottomSampler;** - FBO A texture attachment.

**uniform sampler2D topSampler;** -FBO B texture attachment

I use only plane geometry objects.

The output from this shader is FBO C texture attachment which is blitted into FBO A for the next evolution.

Comment: There's not enough information to be able to answer this question. For example, what kind of blending are you doing? Does your "renderable object" overlap itself? And so forth.

Comment: These are the blend shaders I use : http://mouaif.wordpress.com/2009/01/05/photoshop-math-with-glsl-shaders/   So I do any standard blending. For your second question I don't understand what you mean.Essentially all my objects are planes in 3D space. Every new rendered object is blended with the "background" which stores the accumulated results from the previous renderings.

Comment: @NicolBolas any thoughts? Can order independent transparency approach (using shaders) can be a fit here?